# how to execute shell to install a file from artifacts dir in jenkins

Tags: shell, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I have a build step that builds my projects and packs it into a myfile.jar and put it in my artifacts dir.

i have also told jenkins to archive the myfile.jar.

now i want to add another build step to execute shell command `java -jar myfile.jar` and install it for further testings

how can i tell jenkins to point to myfile.jar when executing the shell command ? i don't know the artifacts dir name since it's dynamically created with build number etc...

thanks.

Comment: Can't you simply run it from the place where the build process puts it? Jenkins artifact archiver does not delete the artifact from the workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The artifacts directory is on the master, not the slave.

If both are on the same machine for you, the artifacts reside at:

```
$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/$BUILD_ID/archive
```

However, like [Anders Lindahl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34148/anders-lindahl) said, archiving an artifact does not delete it from the workspace; why not use it directly from there. Generally, you do not want to disturb the archives directories...

Comment: i understand. so it's better to run it straight from workspace. my question had to do more with how do i access the file if it's dynamically named like '$JOB_NAME-$BUILD_ID.$BUILD_NUMBER.jar' but now now realize that these parameters don't change throughout the build process so i can just use it like 'java -jar ./artifacts/$JOB_NAME-$BUILD_ID.$BUILD_NUMBER.jar'. thanks for the tip.

Comment: Good stuff. I do have a situation that is weird though. I must archive the artifacts, then encrypt the archive before uploading to the FTP site. To prevent installing a bazillion gpg keys to each Jenkins node, I want to perform the encryption on the server side archive, allowing me to set up the keychain in one place. Is the path to the archive the same when a node is used to do the build? Does Jenkins move the archive to the same location?

Comment: @Therealstubot the artifact is always stored on the folder. If you need to encrypt the artifact, I would suggest creating a separate job that runs on the master, and that does the encryption. This can be a downstream job (build after) your main job.

The path to the latest artifact is always `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/lastSuccessful/archive`. The path of the artifact has no reference to the node, so you need not worry about the slave used.